# Apostrophe CMS can't get images in JS beforeSave but can in HTML templates

Tags: image, apostrophe-cms

I have an issue. Here is the schema field defining the image field and the code in the index.js for the pieces module

```
....
{
    name: 'icon',
    label: 'Icon for Title',
    type: 'singleton',
    widgetType: 'apostrophe-images',
    image:true,
    options: {
      aspectRatio: [1, 1],
      minSize: [32, 32],
      limit: 1,
      size: 'iconSize'
    }
  },
  .....
```

and the constructor code

```
....
construct: function (self, options) {

self.beforeSave = function(req, piece, options, callback) {
var d=piece;
var icon=undefined;

console.log('piece log ',d.icon);// piece log  { items:
[ { by: 'id',
   hideTitle: true,
   hideCredits: true,
   hideDescription: true,
   _id: 'w211720719732099649',
   pieceIds: [Array],
   relationships: [Object],
   type: 'apostrophe-images' } ],
   type: 'area' }
   Template warning: Impossible to retrieve the attachment url since it is      missing, a default icon has been set. Please fix this ASAP!

   if (d.icon) {
    var image =self.apos.images.first(d.icon);

    icon = self.apos.attachments.url(image, { size: 'iconSize' });
  }
  console.log('icon log', icon);// icon log /modules/apostrophe-attachments/img/missing-icon.svg
```

*app.js has the image size specified correctly*

Yet in a template file this same code works

```
{% set icon = apos.images.first(data.widget.icon) %}
{% if icon %}
  <img class="event-icon" src="{{ apos.attachments.url(icon) }}" alt="{{ data.widget.navName }}"
  style="{% if apos.attachments.hasFocalPoint(icon) %}background-position: {{ apos.attachments.focalPointToBackgroundPosition(image) }};{% endif %}">
  {% endif %}
```

I can't use the template as I have over 60 fields defined in the schema that creates a whole bunch of HTML so my best option was to create the html in JS and update a schema field with the code which is then output to the template. I've even tried afterSave thinking it was an async issue on the image and that has the same results.

Comment: Can you state plainly what it is you want? Is the above template code too much because of setting a nunjucks variable and then checking if it exists? Are your 60 icon fields within an array? You probably don't want to capture the path of the image in `beforeSave` because it can be different across environments

Comment: I need the URL of the image so I can set it against css generated code. I can't use nunjucks as the projection would be very large for all the settings I have that build the css and html code. I can do it with type attachments but that doesn't enable me to use the apos-images features

Comment: I take your point regarding image urls being different across environments, so what is the solution? Is the slug on the image useful for this purpose?

Comment: You cannot access the image attachment in beforeSave because Apostrophe does not call the loader methods of widgets and perform joins before saving the document. It just saves the widget's contents, including the pieceIds that make the join possible later at document load time.

Since it would not make sense to store those related documents redundantly in the doc for the piece itself in the database Apostrophe does not pay the time overhead to load them at that time.

If your concern is actual code in the template, you can iterate over data structures in templates and use macros.

Comment: Thanks Tom, My issue was having so many schema fields for the piece and projections being very large 60 plus fields. I've now taken a different route of a simple piece that just stores an area, name etc and use a widget that did the same sort of work that the piece did. So it's all being done in nunjucks again. As a side note, I would like to automatically create a copy of the piece when it is placed as a widget so as to not change the (template)piece, any clues?